# PyCharm warns "unresolved attribute reference" when using __subclasses__() despite having the attribute defined in the base class

Tags: python, attributes, pycharm, warnings, subclass

Running the following:

```
class Base:
    x = 1

class A(Base):
    pass

y = Base.__subclasses__()[0].x
```

produces `y=1` as expected. However, PyCharm warns me about the last line:

[image: PyCharm screenshot]

Since all subclasses inherit from `Base` they must contain `x` attribute, therefore I thought it would be obvious for PyCharm to resolve `x`. My original intention with this code was to iterate through all subclasses and find the one with appropriate attribute value.
I've been searching through related questions but couldn't come up with anything better.

What am I missing, and how should I modify my code?

Comment: Thank you! Reported: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-38786

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case: Simply ignore that warning.

I often found that PyCharm isn't really great with metaclasses - and `__subclasses__` is a metaclass method.

In your specific case: PyCharm uses typeshed with the [following definition](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/01b7002a89c2d484c1cac05e3d89808050fa7459/stdlib/2/__builtin__.pyi#L106):

```
class type(object):
    ...
    def __subclasses__(self: _TT) -> List[_TT]: ...
    ...
```

However PyCharm somehow resolves this in your example to `List[type]` instead of the correct `List[Base]`. So `Base.__subclasses__()[0]` has the "inferred type" `type` and because `type` has no attribute `x` it reports the access as "unresolved".

But that's a shortcoming of PyCharm, not your code.

Comment: `List[Base]` -> `List[Type[Base]]`